# My django didnt work(I'm studying in tutorial)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-reversion

I'm very new to django. So I'm studying using tutorial site.
I think type perfectly same on site, but it's not work.
so plz give me advice.

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

mysite/polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),   #url : base/polls/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

mysite/polls/templates/polls/detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if errer_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

part of def vote in mysite/polls/views.py

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

error

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\hdh45\crawling_practice\firstP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:  C:\Users\hdh45\crawling_practice\firstP\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Error during template rendering
In template X:\python\practice_well\polls\templates\polls\detail.html, error at line 5
```

I guess vote url isnt work. maybe something wrong. but i dont know exact anwser. My googling power is useless.. help me.

Comment: in `mysite/polls/templates/polls/detail.htmll` `{% if errer_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}` I believe you misspelled error. Idk if this will help your issue, but it might cause you errors anyway (sorry if you meant to spell it that way)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{% url '***polls***:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
```

polls was a string and your urls.py in a
`path('**<int:question_id>**/vote/', views.vote, name='vote')`
`<int:question_id>` is a `int`. i think that's a mistake

and I'm also begginer